# IQueryable Sort not working

Tags: linq, sorting, iqueryable

What is wrong with the code below with regards to sorting?  The sort code is hit, but the sorting is never applied to the results.

```
var results = new List<Location>();

var county = context.boc_County.Where(x => x.Description.Contains(phrase.ToLower())).ToList();
results.AddRange(_mapper.MapCountyFromDb(county));

var town = context.boc_Town.Where(x => x.Description.Contains(phrase.ToLower())).ToList();
results.AddRange(_mapper.MapTownFromDb(town));

if (orderBy == "Identifier")
{
    if (direction == "ASC")
        results = results.OrderBy(x => x.Identifier);
    else
        results = results.OrderByDescending(x => x.Identifier);
}

if (orderBy == "Type")
{
    if (direction == "ASC")
        results = results.OrderBy(x => x.LocationType.ToString());
    else
        results = results.OrderByDescending(x => x.LocationType.ToString());
}

if (orderBy == "Description")
{
    if (direction == "ASC") 
        results = results.OrderBy(x => x.Description);
    else
        results = results.OrderByDescending(x => x.Description);
}

var model = new LocationSearchResult()
{
    Locations = query.Skip(page * pageSize).Take(pageSize),
    TotalCount = query.Count()
};
return model;
```

Comment: Why are you using `Queryable` at all here? You've got an in memory collection (you're using `ToList`) so why not just keep it as an `IEnumerable<T>`? You're making it more complicated by using `AsQueryable`. Also, we don't know what the various variable values are... it would be much better if you would give us a short but complete example demonstrating the problem.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong. Simplify your code by deleting stuff. You'll find it working eventually. The culprit is what you just deleted.

Comment: Simple explanation: `orderBy` never matches the strings you test it with. You can find such bugs easily with the debugger.

Comment: I'm using Queryable because I then I am able to assign my orderby query.  I'm updating the code to not using a queryable which causes more nested if's.  Usr you are wrong my orderby is being hit.

Comment: I updated the code which as you can see leads to quite a bit more code.  The results are the same, the Ordering never occurs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`OrderBy` and `OrderByDescending` don't change the caller, they return new `IQueryable`/`IEnuemrable` instead. You have to assign it back to another (or the same) variable. Otherwise calling them has no sense.

Because you're using `List<T>` you have to add additional `ToList()` call to make it compile and work:

```
if (orderBy == "Identifier")
{
    if (direction == "ASC")
        results = results.OrderBy(x => x.Identifier).ToList();
    else
        results = results.OrderByDescending(x => x.Identifier).ToList();
}
// (...)
```

or you can use `List<T>.Sort` instead:

```
if (orderBy == "Identifier")
{
    if (direction == "ASC")
        results.Sort((x1, x2) => x1.Compare(x2));
    else
        results.Sort((x1, x2) => x2.Compare(x1));
}
```

Comment: This was only apparent in the changed code. Not sure whether this problem only exists in the "demo" code in this question.

Comment: This is the correct answer.. the assignment was needed as well as the additional .ToList().